# List reshape Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Is there a way to reshape a list ? Just like with an array, my problem is the following: I'd like to have my list L (see below) to have a shape (6,) is there a formula to achieve it ? (I have a similar problem with a code where I need to append several times and at the end I get a list shape (1,1,..,23) and I want to get (23,).

`import numpy as np`
`L = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]`
`L1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

`print(np.shape(L))`
`print(np.shape(L1))`

The output is :
 `(1,6)`
and
`(6,)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `numpy.ndarray.flatten()` equivalent for python lists. As far as I know, there does not exist such functionality out of the box. However, is easily done with list expressions:

```py
L1 = [item for sublist in L for item in sublist]
```

If you can use numpy (as your example suggest), the most straight-forward solution is to apply the flatten method on your arrays:

```py
L = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
L = np.array(L)
L1 = L.flatten()
```

Note that you then switch to numpy arrays.

Comment: Ok thanks for your list expression it worked indeed! And the other solution would be to transform my list into an array (should I use `np.asarray` ?) and then use the `np.ndarray` method ?

Comment: Indeed, first transform your list into an array. You can do this with the method `np.array` or `np.asarray`. The latter actually calls the former, but it sets some variables for you. They are almost equivalent, but I prefer `np.array` as it has more variables to set if you want. Once you have used `np.array`, you have an `np.ndarray` object that has the method `flatten()`. I've rewritten my answer a bit so that it becomes more clear

Comment: You're welcome. Also something to note: The flatten method is slightly more powerful/versatile, since it does not require any information on the shape of your list/array. Even if you have a list with, for example, shape (2,4,6) you will have a one-dimensional array after applying `.flatten()`. The list expression includes information of your shape (the amount of forloops in the list expression).

Comment: Ok so image now that I have  `L = [[[1,2,3,4,5,6]]]` the first method you gave with the list wouldn't work? So I should do it with the `flatten` method ?

Comment: Indeed, because this solution  loops over 'lists in a list', and not 'lists in a list in a list' if that makes sense. You therefore have to rewrite a similar list expression that takes an additional 'layer' into account. Not hard, but if you have to do this many times it becomes cumbersome. `flatten` does this work for you and makes a one-dimensional array, regardless of the nesting level